# Pushing a string to a private member vector

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, c++14, push-back

I have a `std::vector<std::string> tileSet_` as a member variable of a class. In the constructor of said class I call the function

```
void MapWindow::shuffleTiles() const
{
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned>> tileAmounts = {
    {"a", 2}, {"b", 4}, {"c", 1}, {"d", 4},
    {"e", 5}, {"f", 2}, {"g", 1}, {"h", 3},
    {"i", 2}, {"j", 3}, {"k", 3}, {"l", 3},
    {"m", 2}, {"n", 3}, {"o", 2}, {"p", 3},
    {"q", 1}, {"r", 3}, {"s", 2}, {"t", 1},
    {"u", 8}, {"v", 9}, {"w", 4}, {"x", 1}
  };

  int tileN = 0;
  for (std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>::size_type i = 0;
    i < tileAmounts.size();i++) {
    tileN += tileAmounts.at(i).second;
  }

  // only used once to initialise (seed) engine
  std::random_device rd;
  // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
  std::mt19937 rng(rd());
  // guaranteed unbiased
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(0,tileAmounts.size() - 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < tileN; i++) {
    auto random_integer = uni(rng);
    //qDebug() << i << ":" << random_integer;
    std::cout << i
              << ":"
              << tileAmounts.at(random_integer).first
              << ":"
              << tileAmounts.at(random_integer).second
              << std::endl
              << std::endl;

    while (tileAmounts.at(random_integer).second < 1) {
      std::cout << "Reshuffling "
               << tileAmounts.at(random_integer).first
               << ":"
               << tileAmounts.at(random_integer).second
               << std::endl;
      random_integer = uni(rng);
    }

    std::string s = tileAmounts[random_integer].first;
    std::cout << s
              << std::endl;

    tileSet_.push_back(s);
    tileAmounts.at(random_integer).second -= 1;
  }

  for (std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0;
    i < tileSet_.size();i++) {
    std::cout << tileSet_.at(i)
              << std::endl;
  }
}
```

which at the very end attempts to push back a randomly picked string from a pair contained in the vector `tileAmounts` into the memeber vector. For some reason, this raises the error

```
no matching member function call to 'push_back'
```

Why does this happen. I'm taking the vector to be pushed back from a `std::pair`, but surely that shouldn't be causing any type mismatches? A `std::string` in a `std::pair` contained in a `std::vector` is still a `std::string`, no?

Comment: We can't reproduce the problem (without making guesses). Please provide enough code so that we can simply cut/paste the code and generate the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a while to get it all building (with some guesses).

The problem is that the method is marked `const`. Thus you are not allowed to call any mutating functions on members (ie you can not call none const member functions or none const member functions on any member variables).

```
 void MapWindow::shuffleTiles() const
                                ^^^^^
 ...
     tileSet_.push_back(s);  // Attempt to mutate the state of the object.
```

This is explained in greate detail in the error message generated by the compiler:

```
t2.cpp:61:14: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
    tileSet_.push_back(s);
    ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:712:36: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
      'const std::vector<std::string>' (aka 'const vector<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >'), but method is not marked const
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(const_reference __x);
                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:715:36: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
      'const std::vector<std::string>' (aka 'const vector<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >'), but method is not marked const
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(value_type&& __x);
```

If you go to the end of the line it says: "**but method is not marked const**"

Deciphering line:

> note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
>   'const std::vector', but method is not marked const
>   void push_back(const_reference __x);
>
> note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
>   'const std::vector', but method is not marked const
>   void push_back(value_type&& __x);

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the source of the problem: the vector`tileSet_` didn't use to be a member variable, but I made it so out of necessity. I had, however, originally defined the function `shuffleTiles` as a `const` function, which of course makes it impossible for it to change the state of the class. Removing the `const` from the definition fixed the issue.

The error messages in C++ can sure be mystical.